# How to get second ListView take all space in Column?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have got parent Widget:

```
return  Column(children: [
     Windget1(), // I tried to make both of them Expanded
     Windget2(), 
 ]
```

`Windget1` and `Windget2` are `ListView` and look like:

```
   ListView.builder(
       shrinkWrap: true,
       controller: ScrollController(),
       itemBuilder: (ctx, idx) =>
       SingleJobItem(controller.jobList[idx], key: UniqueKey()),
       itemCount: controller.jobList.length)
     );
```

At start `Widgets1` display containers, that should be moved to `Widget2` and `Widget2` should take all available space, but it do not happens. It's take only half of size.

I tried different combinations with wrapping `Column`'s widgets in Expand, Tried to remove/add flexible in Widget1/2, but nothing do not work.

What I am seeing on start:
[image]

What I am getting at result:

[image]

I need to make second take all available space.

I tried to make one of Widget Expanded, but it five me overflow:

```
return  Column(
    children: [
    
    Widget1(),
    Expanded(child: Widget2())
    ]
 )
```

[image]

Comment: I tried, do not work

Comment: Bind your column with `SingleChildScrollView`

Comment: @JahidulIslam, yes, it's helped! But Is it's single way? Or I can try something another?

Comment: I think you can go for it. what did you mean something another?

Comment: @Jahidul Islam yes it's work, I do not understand why it's do not without it, and what I can try else to learn another solutins.

Comment: SingleChildScrollView is a box where we can scroll a single widget. Like Column.

Comment: updated my comment as answer, for more read from here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html

Answer (score 1):

Bind your column with `SingleChildScrollView`

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Stack(
   children:[
      Column(
      children: [
         // your widgets 
      ]
    ),
    Align(
     alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
     child: //your button
     )
   ]
  )
)
```

Comment: Sorry, I removed your answer from the correct because it looked correct only at beginning. Later I understood that it's make by UI scrollable and I can't add button to down.

Comment: easily add button using stack and update my answer with stack

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its helpful to you. just try add `padding: EdgeInsets.zero,`

```
     ListView.builder(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: 10,
                  physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Container(
                         child:Text('Add Text! '),
                    );
                  },
                ),
```

Comment: I tried, do now  work :(

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correctly then, wrap your Widget2() inside Expanded and do not use any Expanded in Widget1():

```
return  Column(children: [
     Windget1(), 
    Expanded(child: Windget2()), 
 ]
```

Comment: yes, it's first that I tried, but it do not work

Comment: The thing is that I could not understand your question properly, if you could explain it more clearly, that would help.